# How to extract a specific data from the json using python

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, google-maps

I want to extract the "long_name" data present in the "address_components" in the below given json. The challenge is I want only the "long_name" data whose "types" is "administrative_area_level_2". please let me know how to extract only that specific data preferably in python. Thanks

edit: Note that js["results"][0]["address_components"][2]["long_name"] is not how I want to extract its value since ["address_components"][2] keeps varying for the different locations given as input. my main criteria is to extract data of "long_name" whose "types" is always "administrative_area_level_2"

```
{
    "status": "OK", 
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE", 
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.9177876, 
                        "lng": 80.24104
                    }, 
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.875989, 
                        "lng": 80.20860669999999
                    }
                }, 
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.9177876, 
                        "lng": 80.24104
                    }, 
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.875989, 
                        "lng": 80.20860669999999
                    }
                }, 
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.9009877, 
                    "lng": 80.2279301
                 }
            }, 
            "formatted_address": "Sholinganallur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India", 
            "place_id": "ChIJGzh_3nlbUjoRGz_-itQtu_8", 
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Sholinganallur", 
                    "types": [
                        "sublocality_level_1", 
                        "sublocality", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "Sholinganallur"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "Chennai", 
                    "types": [
                        "locality", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "Chennai"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "Kanchipuram", 
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "Kanchipuram"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "Tamil Nadu", 
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "TN"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "India", 
                    "types": [
                        "country", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "IN"
                }
            ], 
            "partial_match": true, 
            "types": [
                "sublocality_level_1", 
                "sublocality", 
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The below is the code which I am trying but I get output only till location. Let me know what changes I need to make in my code.

```
import urllib
import json

apiurl= 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = apiurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':     address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

    print 'Retrieved',len(uh),'characters'
    js = json.loads(str(uh))
    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)   
    jayz = js["results"][0]
    lat = jayz["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = jayz["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
    location = jayz['formatted_address']
    print location
    components = js["results"][0]["address_components"]
    names = [component['long_name'] for component in components if 'administrative_area_level_2' in component['types']]
    name = names[0]
    print "District:", name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the components and loop on them and find the ones that you

```
js = eval(input_file.read())
components =  js["results"][0]["address_components"]
names = [component['long_name'] for component in components if 'administrative_area_level_2' in component['types']]
```

Here, names will include long_name of all the components that have administrative_area_level_2 in their types

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your help. but can you answer based on my code above? thanks in advance

Comment: it is based on your code! js is your json test evaluated into a dict. I can  update that

Comment: Hey Niki it worked , thanks I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This is one liner solution if you like it

it is in python

```
my_long_names = [[component.get("long_name") for component  in result.get("address_components") if "administrative_area_level_2" in component.get("types")] for result in data.get("results") ]
print my_long_names
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your help. but can you answer based on my code above? thanks.